# MVVM: Frame navigation within page

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, windows-10

My app is utilizing a `SplitView` which has a `Frame` as it's content. I can't seem to figure out how to use the buttons in my split view to change pages in the frame. Right now i'm trying to bind the `SourcePageType` to my view model, but that doesn't work. Here is my setup.

Frame

```
<SplitView.Content>
        <Frame x:Name="frame" SourcePageType="{Binding FrameSource}">
            <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <NavigationThemeTransition>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                            <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo/>
                        </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                    </NavigationThemeTransition>
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Frame.ContentTransitions>
        </Frame>
    </SplitView.Content>
```

View Model

```
private string frameSource;
    public string FrameSource
    {
        get { return frameSource; }
        set
        {
            frameSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FrameSource");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> navCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> NavCommand
    {
        get
        {
            navCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(ExecuteNav);
            return navCommand;
        }
    }
    public void ExecuteNav(string page)
    {
        FrameSource = page;
    }
```

I'm using MVVM Light for my framework. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/

Comment: You can also take a look at [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) which encapsulates all of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I also have been struggling with this using mmvm light and came up with this method which I use in the main window with a content control bound to the selected viewmodel I want to show. It may be somewhat overkill, but it works and its not too difficult to maintain.

In the main page view model I create a menu object:

```
  private void constructMenu()
    {
        MenuMessages = new ObservableCollection<MenuMessage>();
        MenuMessages.Add(new MenuMessage
        {
            menutext = "FirstPage",
            isactive = true,
            newWindow = false,
            viewModelName = "FirstPageViewModel"
        });
        MenuMessages.Add(new MenuMessage
        {
            menutext = "2page",
            isactive = true,
            newWindow = false,
            viewModelName = "2pageViewModel"
        });
```

I have the following INotifyable properties:

```
 public MenuMessage selectedmenuitem
  public ObservableCollection<MenuMessage> MenuMessages
 public Object selectedViewModel
```

in addition each view model that I use is an INotifyable propery

```
public FirstPageViewModel firstpageviewmodel;
public 2PageViewModel firstpageviewmodel;
```

My main page xaml looks like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myproj"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Myproj.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Myproj.ViewModel"
    x:Class="Myproj.MainWindow"  mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FirstPageViewModel}">
        <Views:FirstPageView/>

    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:2PageViewModel}">
        <Views2pageView/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
<DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuMessages}"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedmenuitem}" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate> <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>                    
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding menutext}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
     </StackPanel>  

        <ContentControl  Content="{Binding selectedVM}" ></ContentControl>
 </DockPanel>
```

In the viewmodel I call the following method after the RaisePropertyChanged of the selectedmenuitem setter:

```
 private void switchviewmodel()
    {
        switch (selectedmenuitem.viewModelName)
        {
            case "FirstPageViewModel":
                selectedVM = irstpageviewmodel;
                break;
            case "2PageViewModel":
                selectedVM = 2pageviewmodel;
                break;
         }
    }
```